# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, server

Trying to make a POST request with python from my desktop to my Bitcoin node running on raspberrypi. The two devices are running on the same network both connected by ethernet. I have been able to make a POST request using `curl` from the node's command line (ssh from the desktop). The command looks like this:

`curl -v -u <rpcuser>:<rpcpassword> -d '{"method":"getblockcount","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8332/`

It gives me the output just fine, but when I write a python script from my desktop to send the same POST request, it gives me the error in the title. The python code looks like this:

`request = requests.post(url=self.url, json={"method":"getblockhash","params":[0],"id":1}, headers={'Authorization':'Basic <base64 encoding of rpcuser:rpcpass>'})`

I have tried both the auth and the headers parameter and they both give me the same error. How can I pass in the rpcuser and password to successfully make a request?

Answer (score 1):

When making requests to a different network device, you need to replace `localhost` with that device's IP address. On a Raspberry Pi specifically you can use this command to find it:

```
hostname -I
```

The credentials should be sent using [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). This means you need to set the `Authorization` header field to `Basic <credential>`, where `<credential>` is the Base64 encoding of username and password joined by a single colon `:`.

Comment: I have a couple questions. Do I need to replace `localhost` with the pi's IP address if the two devices are connected to the same network? The request seems to go through without replacing `localhost`. Second, I have created an authorization header that looks like: `header = {'Authorization' : 'basic <base64 encoding of rpc_user:rpc_password>'}` and it does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: I have tried changing `localhost` to the pi's IP address and I have created a header for the request. It is still not working. Would you have any idea why?

Comment: "It is still not working" is not a helpful problem description. What error do you get? What network traffic do you observe?

Comment: Sending the request gives me the same error: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."